# A Regex for looking after pattern (many occurs) but only till a substring

Tags: python, regex

There is a regex I use to collect all the names in a long text file (Multi line):

```
regex = 'Name:\s*(.*)$'
names = re.findall(regex, file_content)
```

The file contains several sections, and I need to collect names only up to a specific substring (for example, "computers:"). It is possible to do this with Python (e.g., cut the `file_content` after the substring), but for some reason, I must use regex only.

How?

Example for the text file:

```
Name:     Jon
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231
Name:     Mon
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231
Name:     Gon
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231

Computers:

Name:     Jason
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231
Name:     Bason
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231
```

Output:
Jon, Mon, Gon

Comment: Can you add sample text and expected output?

Comment: Just use the string on the right of `.*` - `regex = 'Name:\s*(.*?)\s*computers:'`

Comment: @shaikmoeed I added

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thx, but It finds only the first

Comment: Then `regex = 'Name:\s*(.*)(?=[\s\S]*computers:)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
regex = 'Name:\s*(.*)(?=[\s\S]*computers:)'
```

Here,

- `Name:` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?=[\s\S]*computers:)` - immediately to the right, there must be any zero or more chars followed with `computers:` string

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

file_content = """
Name:     Jon
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231
Name:     Mon
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231
Name:     Gon
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231

Computers:

Name:     Jason
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231
Name:     Bason
  address: 1st 
  phone: 01321231231231
"""

#names = re.findall(r'Name:.*\n', file_content)

# To match only till some specific string in that case you
# can do slicing and use your portion of interest.
names = re.findall(r'Name:.*\n', file_content[:file_content.index("Computers")])

final_name_list = []

for name in names:
    final_name_list.append(name.replace("Name:     ", "").replace("\n", ""))

print(final_name_list)
```

In re.findall, match your line which starts with "Name:" and
ends with new line.

```
names = re.findall(r'Name:.*\n', file_content) #this matches to all
names = re.findall(r'Name:.*\n', file_content[:file_content.index("Computers")]) #this matches only till the "Compters"
```

list names will have the line with the string that you need, that you can replace with null string by iterating over the each list elements.

```
final_name_list.append(name.replace("Name:     ", "").replace("\n", ""))
```

Comment: indexing part ```file_content[:file_content.index("Computers")])```  will make this search till the before "Computers"